# Pixelated Image Sizing on JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, resize

So I am using the following code on a javascript canvas. When I resize the img it gets really pixelated...

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "file.png"

ctx.drawImage(img,10,10,100,100)
```

Why is it so bad quality!? Thank you in advance!

Size of canvas: 620x328

Size of pic: 2048x1536

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE]. We need to know : the size of the original image, the size of the canvas (its `width` and `height` attributes), its display size (the one set by CSS)

Comment: @Kaiido done :)

Comment: and are you setting this canvas size through the canvas element's properties/attributes (`canvas.width = 620; canvas.height=328` / `<canvas width="620" height="328"…`) or through CSS only? Your image should be stretched anyway since you don't respect its size ratio, but it should not be *pixelatted*

Comment: @Kaiido <canvas width="620" height= "328"> I found that setting the file from png to svg fixes the problem :)